# EMF Detector Sensitivity

Tags: arduino, resistors, noise, antenna

A fun little project I've been working on is an EMF detector using my recently acquired Arduino. It is based off of the guide at http://www.aaronalai.com/emf-detector, primary differences being my own implementation of value smoothing and outputting Geiger-counter-style popping with a piezo element (just because it sounds cool, hehe).

Now from what I understand the principle behind the operation of the detector is that changes in electric fields are inducing a potential in the antenna wire, which is then read by the Arduino... However since I'm quite new to the whole electronics scene I do not know the function the 3.3 meg-ohm resistor holds (it grounds the antenna wire, as seen in the link above), and more specifically, what kind of effects increasing or decreasing the resistance actually has on the setup (yes, I have tested this, however since the setup is so so sensitive I can't discover a pattern... I figured finding what makes it work would help).

So if someone could explain the effects of the resistor in the circuit, it would be greatly appreciated (more so if any proper terminology is pointed out, its a learning experience for me!)

Comment: We'll need a schematic - I can't see one at that link.

Comment: By the looks of it there's no schematic to speak of...  Aerial -> A5.  A5->3.3MΩ->GND.  Some digital pin being used as an output with LED+resistor to ground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I watched the video - the resistor will change the sensitivity of the device.

It's basically a charge detector. The antenna picks up a charge from a nearby object which turns the input FET on/off.
The resistor controls how quickly the charge will dissipate to ground, and therefore how sensitive the circuit is to external e-fields.

You can build the same thing using one FET, 9V battery, resistor and LED.

Here is an [example circuit](http://amasci.com/emotor/chargdet.html#1) with an *excellent* description of what is happening.

In the second version of the Arduino version an LCD + averaging algorithm is used to low pass filter the readings and provide a numeric display of the field strength.

Comment: So by this logic, lowering the resistance should increase sensitivity (and the inverse vice versa)? (And considering the project in your link, the issues associated with lowering the resistance are less protection against ESD?)

Comment: I think the project you link to actually uses a resistor between the analogue pin and *ground*. This is not to be confused with the 1 Meg resistor in the circuit I link to, which simply protects the FET gate. The 3M3 resistor to ground in the Arduino version will set the impedance to ground to a known level, and sensitivity should drop if you lower the resistance (and vice versa) It would work without it present, but having a known level of input impedance is usually a good thing (for calculations/calibration etc)

Comment: I misinterpreted the example you provided then, thanks for clearing that up - as I said in my question: "3.3 meg-ohm resistor holds (it grounds the antenna wire"

Cheers for the help!